# Any code improvement in adding/replacing fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I have started to study Kotlin and do not know all the functionality of the language.

The function is used to show the fragment in the FrameLayout. The logic is so that the first time it should always `add()` the fragment and next times it will `replace()`. Also in some cases I need to use `addToBackStack()`  and also in the same situations to disable the left-side menu.

```
fun showFragment(fragment : Fragment,
                 isReplace: Boolean = true,
                 backStackTag: String? = null,
                 isEnabled: Boolean = true)
{
    /* Defining fragment transaction */
    val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()

    /* Select if to replace or add a fragment */
    if(isReplace)
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayoutContent, fragment, backStackTag)
    else
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frameLayoutContent, fragment)

    /* Select if to add to back stack */
    if(backStackTag != null)
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragment.javaClass.name)

    fragmentTransaction.commit()
    enableDrawer(isEnabled)
}
```

**Question:** Are there some possible improvements of the function code related to the specifications of Kotlin language to make code cleaner as for now the function looks as a mass.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

***I have posted a [blog](https://medium.com/thoughts-overflow/how-to-add-a-fragment-in-kotlin-way-73203c5a450b) about the below answer.***

I will write an [`Extension function`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) to the `FragmentManager` which accepts a [`Lambda with Receiver`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver) as an argument.

```
inline fun FragmentManager.inTransaction(func: FragmentTransaction.() -> Unit) {
    val fragmentTransaction = beginTransaction()
    fragmentTransaction.func()
    fragmentTransaction.commit()
}
```

To add a `fragment`, we can call like this from the `Activity` now:

```
supportFragmentManager.inTransaction {
    add(R.id.frameLayoutContent, fragment)
}
```

The advantage of this is we don't have to call `beginTransaction()` and  `commit()` every time we add or replace a `Fragment` now. How many hours have you wasted debugging only to find out that you have missed calling `commit()` in Java?

Next, I will write `Extension functions` to `AppCompatActivity`:

```
fun AppCompatActivity.addFragment(fragment: Fragment, frameId: Int, backStackTag: String? = null) {
    supportFragmentManager.inTransaction {
        add(frameId, fragment)
        backStackTag?.let { addToBackStack(fragment.javaClass.name) }
    }
}

fun AppCompatActivity.replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment, frameId: Int, backStackTag: String? = null) {
    supportFragmentManager.inTransaction {
        replace(frameId, fragment)
        backStackTag?.let { addToBackStack(fragment.javaClass.name) }
    }
}
```

So that now we can add/ replace `Fragment` from any `Activity` in a single line, without any additional qualifiers:

```
addFragment(yourFragment, R.id.frameLayoutContent, "tag")

replaceFragment(yourFragment, R.id.frameLayoutContent, "tag")
```

Comment: Posted a blog explaining this: https://medium.com/thoughts-overflow/how-to-add-a-fragment-in-kotlin-way-73203c5a450b

Comment: Nice answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I like to use [with](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/with.html) and [let](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html) when I have some code related to using a lot some variable and [null checks](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/idioms.html#execute-if-not-null)

So I'd do something like this:

```
fun showFragment(fragment : Fragment,
                 isReplace: Boolean = true,
                 backStackTag: String? = null,
                 isEnabled: Boolean = true)
{
    /* Defining fragment transaction */
    with(supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()) {

        /* Select if to replace or add a fragment */
        if(isReplace)
            replace(R.id.frameLayoutContent, fragment, backStackTag)
        else
            add(R.id.frameLayoutContent, fragment)

        /* Select if to add to back stack */
        backStackTag?.let { addToBackStack(it) }

        commit()
    }
    enableDrawer(isEnabled)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine. Probably here

```
if(backStackTag != null)
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragment.javaClass.name)
```

you want to add fragment using `backStackTag` like this

```
if(backStackTag != null)
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(backStackTag)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension function like this:

1. Import `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` and `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction` if you wish to make your app compatible with devices running system versions as low as Android 1.6 using `supportFragmentManager`(which uses the support library) instead of `fragmentManager`.
2. Define the following function on the top level, i.e. directly under the package:

   ```
   inline fun FragmentManager.inTransaction(func: FragmentTransaction.() Unit) {
       val fragmentTransaction = beginTransaction()
       fragmentTransaction.func()
       fragmentTransaction.commit() 
   }
   ```
3. Call the function from any activity:

   ```
   supportFragmentManager.inTransaction {
       add(R.id.frameLayoutContent, fragment)
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for replace:

```
fun Fragment.moveAnotherFragment(fragment: Fragment,addToBackStack: Boolean = true, func : Bundle?. () -> Unit = {}) {

fragment.enterTransition =
    activity?.supportFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.apply {
        replace(
            R.id.frame, fragment.apply {
                enterTransition = Slide(Gravity.END)
                exitTransition = Slide(Gravity.START)
                arguments.apply(func)
            }
        )
        if (addToBackStack) addToBackStack(null)
        commit()
    }
```

}